# Java Jackson behaves differently when app run as jar instead of from Eclipse

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, gradle, jackson

I'm trying to convert incoming JSON data into Java objects using Jackson. The client sends a JSON via POST request of the form

```
{
    "PlayerID" : "e32ce780-d5ca-4230-994b-4bb9ed7ca180",
    "GameName" : "test",
    "Difficulty" : 20
}
```

This then should get converted into a GameCreationRequest, using this constructor:

```
    @JsonCreator
    public GameCreationRequest(
            @JsonProperty(value = JSONnames.PLAYER_ID, required = true) NetworkPlayerIdentifier netPlayerID, 
            @JsonProperty(value = JSONnames.GAME_NAME, required = true) String gameName, 
            @JsonProperty(value = JSONnames.DIFFICULTY, required = true) int difficulty) {
        this.netPlayerID = netPlayerID;
        this.gameName = gameName;
        this.difficulty = difficulty;
    }
```

The constructor for the NetworkPlayerIdentifier:

```
    @JsonCreator
    public NetworkPlayerIdentifier(String identifier) {
        this.identifier = identifier;
    }
```

Now, if I run my spring project via Eclipse and send a request with JSON data as mentioned above this works perfectly. However, if I build a bootJar using Gradle and run the .jar file, I get this exception (package names removed and replaced with ..):

```
JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `...NetworkPlayerIdentifier` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('e32ce780-d5ca-4230-994b-4bb9ed7ca180'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `...NetworkPlayerIdentifier` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('e32ce780-d5ca-4230-994b-4bb9ed7ca180')
```

Now, if I change the JSON data I send to

```
{
    "PlayerID" : {"PlayerID" : "e32ce780-d5ca-4230-994b-4bb9ed7ca180"},
    "GameName" : "test2",
    "Difficulty" : 20
}
```

everything works as expected. Now, why does the produced jar behave so differently and how can I fix that (I don't want to change the form of the JSON data I send)? I could not find anything about such a problem so far, so the mistake is very likely on my part.

I've already tried adding @JsonProperty to the String parameter of the NetworkPlayerIdentifier constructor, which does not help.

As this is my first stackoverflow question I am sorry if I did any formal mistakes in asking my question.

Edit 1: Here the full *Show Command Line* output from Eclipse:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.7.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-classpath /Users/Tobi/JavaPlayground/Sudoku/bin/main:/Users/Tobi/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-websocket/2.6.1/e5e467d190eacb26fdcb404d9a926807e4bd54ca/spring-boot-starter-websocket-2.6.1.jar:/Users/Tobi/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web/2.6.1/145ac0cfb81982608ef0d19e32699c0eeeb3c2ab/spring-boot-starter-web-2.6.1.jar:/Users/Tobi/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-json/2.6.1/b76ad5d869508cc78aaf00bb7ab92e8a472b26ed/spring-boot-starter-json-2.6.1.jar:/Users/Tobi/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter/2.6.1/39d77929829c82b102248630047abf0f69b96a7b/spring-boot-starter-2.6.1.jar:/Users/Tobi/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/2.6.1/6a0744acdd17b860e2ba3edb95c3c7cec36e6b58/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.6.1.jar:/Users/Tobi/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/5.3.13/cea31c85fa84dbd9f8df14a3ca62ab57c25cabe4/spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:/Users/Tobi/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-websocket/5.3.13/638d7e46a2f3a6348f7e5defaa3953b29c948ca8/spring-websocket-5.3.13.jar:/Users/Tobi/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-web/5.3.13/66d95a5d2d436961b4cae036723f4c7a764fc14c/spring-web-5.3.13.jar:/Users/Tobi/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-messaging/5.3.13/541b3e6462b5cc6e8cb59af25ca1743db2436cab/spring-messaging-5.3.13.jar:/Users/Tobi/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/2.6.1/9ac07afd64da0cce435792ba1328c93edcfbb2fb/spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.1.jar:/Users/Tobi/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot/2.6.1/f670cee55752c1f1b304508e18bafd000e543174/spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:/Users/Tobi/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/2.6.1/2f83b93ec87bf2f1e28e67c9a6cec80f9c0032/spring-boot-starter-logging-2.6.1.jar:/Users/Tobi/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/jakarta.annotation/jakarta.annotation-api/1.3.5/59eb84ee0d616332ff44aba065f3888cf002cd2d/jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar:/Users/Tobi/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-context/5.3.13/e328db1c30ffe1c58328e4ab42cd3855a5307469/spring-context-5.3.13.jar:/Users/Tobi/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-expression/5.3.13/8f7448f4fb296a92855fd0afea3375ce41061e84/spring-expression-5.3.13.jar:/Users/Tobi/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-aop/5.3.13/e0fddf47af3fbbec69a403c058c23505612ca329/spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:/Users/Tobi/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-beans/5.3.13/1d90c96b287253ec371260c35fbbea719c24bad6/spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:/Users/Tobi/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-core/5.3.13/d2a6c3372dd337e08144f9f49f386b8ec7a8080d/spring-core-5.3.13.jar:/Users/Tobi/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.yaml/snakeyaml/1.29/6d0cdafb2010f1297e574656551d7145240f6e25/snakeyaml-1.29.jar:/Users/Tobi/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310/2.13.0/4c143877fc733befe6189151c8b95d84acd06941/jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.13.0.jar:/Users/Tobi/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.module/jackson-module-parameter-names/2.13.0/62a5e3b6cc5aacc0ff2354053f3cc2a7821dfa9/jackson-module-parameter-names-2.13.0.jar:/Users/Tobi/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.13.0/15be89db6609bd6fda3dc309bacf0318a312c03f/jackson-annotations-2.13.0.jar:/Users/Tobi/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.13.0/e957ec5442966e69cef543927bdc80e5426968bb/jackson-core-2.13.0.jar:/Users/Tobi/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-jdk8/2.13.0/6d82a502e03f61d6dc6e47e5f7d6168141419c92/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.13.0.jar:/Users/Tobi/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.13.0/889672a1721d6d85b2834fcd29d3fda92c8c8891/jackson-databind-2.13.0.jar:/Users/Tobi/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/9.0.55/4e6dc3646d00887497bd465bc4a63bfb0a7b10ab/tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.55.jar:/Users/Tobi/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-core/9.0.55/6ab68425d34f35e93cf97e1950c2c710161d8ce1/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:/Users/Tobi/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-el/9.0.55/d8b69643d1566712cf849a7e8e95c917f8aed1d3/tomcat-embed-el-9.0.55.jar:/Users/Tobi/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.2.7/3e89a85545181f1a3a9efc9516ca92658502505b/logback-classic-1.2.7.jar:/Users/Tobi/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-to-slf4j/2.14.1/ce8a86a3f50a4304749828ce68e7478cafbc8039/log4j-to-slf4j-2.14.1.jar:/Users/Tobi/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.32/8a055c04ab44e8e8326901cadf89080721348bdb/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.32.jar:/Users/Tobi/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-jcl/5.3.13/3aa15be194887fbda3912ecbb4ab6ec8dfdebdb0/spring-jcl-5.3.13.jar:/Users/Tobi/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch.qos.logback/logback-core/1.2.7/31f7db3c4277023742268c0c3f9b65f1f297e49a/logback-core-1.2.7.jar:/Users/Tobi/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.32/cdcff33940d9f2de763bc41ea05a0be5941176c3/slf4j-api-1.7.32.jar:/Users/Tobi/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api/2.14.1/cd8858fbbde69f46bce8db1152c18a43328aae78/log4j-api-2.14.1.jar org.prisching.tobias.Sudoku.main.SudokuApplication
```

Edit 2: I've created a basic project which shows the same behaviour: https://github.com/TechnikTobi/springTest1
If you the project from within Eclipse and send Post requests to localhost:8086/app/createGame with the above mentioned JSON, it works fine. However, "exporting" it via Gradle with the bootJar task results in the described problem.

Comment: Please show the command line used to run as JAR and the command line that is shown in Eclipse in the launch configuration when you click the _Show Command Line_ button.

Comment: Please edit your question instead of adding comments. Is it related to the working directory (try to run the command line from Eclipse in an empty directory)? Is `java` and `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.7.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java` the same?

Comment: @howlger Edited question to include full Show Command Line Output. As it turns out ```java```and ```/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.7.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java``` is not the same as ```java -version```gives me ```java version "17.0.1" 2021-10-19 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.1+12-LTS-39)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.1+12-LTS-39, mixed mode, sharing)```